# How to move all references into another folder

Tags: .net, reference, .net-assembly

I have a project with a lot of references. They are all in the same directory with .exe file. Sometimes is hard to find .exe, because it is too many files.

How can I move references to another folder in the project?

Comment: That's how build mechanism works to put all referenced assemblies alongside your exe.

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion would be to look for simple ways to work around the issue - Do you *need* to find the exe in the output folder? (Really?!) Can you put a shortcut to the .exe somewhere more convenient so you don't have to search for it? Can you create a batch file that copies the file(s) you want to a different deployment location? Can you automate whatever fiddling that you are doing to the .exe so you never need to go near the output folder yourself?

If you really want to play with the build process, then...

**Warning:** *Messing with the stuff below could break your build and it is almost certainly going to cause more trouble than it is worth sometime in the future. Try it carefully on a backup and only commit to changes if you're happy with the results! Also, make sure you use relative folder paths if you reference filenames or any attempt to put your source code into a different folder will break everything.*

DLLs referenced by your application can be placed in sub-folders next to the .exe and it should find them and run normally. However, by default the Visual Studio build process will copy referenced dlls alongside the exe (not into a subfolder).

This copying step can be disabled in each reference's properties - turn off the "Copy Local" option. (You'll need to also clean your Debug/Release folders to get rid of any old copies of the DLLs, or things will appear to work but gradually stop working as the old DLLs get more and more out of date with your code changes). Without the dlls copied locally, the exe will not run, so you will need to invent your own way of building the deployed file structure (your subfolder of dlls).

There are various solutions to this, but one of the simplest approaches (that is least likely to break anything else) is to add a post-build event command that copies the dll files into your deployment location. You can either copy the references into your Debug/Release folder next to the .exe, or you can choose to copy the exe and all its dependencies to a completely different location. Note that you'll need to do an "only copy if newer" if you want to avoid unnecessarily slowing down your builds.

(Another option is to change the output folder for each of your projects, or for the entire solution build, but that is more likely to break a lot of stuff)

I wouldn't recommend doing this though. Even if you know what you're doing, fighting against the normal build process is very likely to end in a fragile or broken build system.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to do this things with a backup of my project, but every try was failed.